# Converting Binary Number to Decimal using recursion technique

Tags: java, recursion, binary, decimal

As the title says i was trying to convert binary to decimal using recursive technique in java but i cannot get the desire output 
here's what i did

```
   public class deci {
       public static void main(String args[]){
           hexa s1=new deci();
           s1.spawn(11000);
       }
       void spawn(int a){
           int p=0;int x=0;int k=0;
           if(a>0){
               p=a%10;
               x=x+p*(int)Math.pow(2,k);
               k++;
               spawn(a/10);
           } else {
               System.out.print(x);
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: And what's the desired output? What output did you get? Make an effort, man.

Comment: i get 00110 instead of 12

Comment: so what problem this code really has ??

Comment: Well, you're not passing the value of k anywhere for one, so it's always 0.

Comment: can you correct it out ? please

Comment: You say you're trying to convert binary to decimal (e.g. 1101 -> 13) but it looks like the code might be trying to do the opposite?

Anyway, true recursion takes the results of the method call and uses them itself. You make a call to spawn() but spawn() doesn't return anything and doesn't alter the state of anything (since p, x and k are all local variables to the method)... so it's not surprising it's not working. You need to review what recursion is and how you can apply it to the problem at hand.

Comment: I suggest you use `1 << n` instead of `Math.pow(2, n)` as it is 100x more expensive.

Comment: @Sigma I won't write out the code for you, but I can help you with it. I already mentioned that you increment 'k', but never do anything with it.

Comment: @Sigma also peter's answer a pretty good pointer to figure out the problem . In case still you want some one to write  the code better try google instead of SO .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you ar not using the result of spawn, either returning or printing it.

If you want to return it, you need the shifting or power, but it you want to print it.

I suggest you step through the code in your debugger so you can see what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working program.

Parameters are (binary code, size of code-1) e.g. for (111, 2) this will return 7

```
int binaryToDecimal(int binary,int size){  
  if(binary==0) return 0;        
  return binary%10*(int)Math.pow(2,size)+binaryToDecimal((int)binary/10,size-1);  
}
```